# TimeSeries graph plot for Sentiment Analysis output using resample() python

Tags: pandas, time-series, sentiment-analysis

I have a set of timestamps for twitter feeds and their respective output sentiment values stored in a csv. I need to aggregate the sentiment value against 6 hour periods and plot a time series graph. Please help, I am trying to do this using resample() in pandas.

```
Sat Oct 01 00:43:02 +0000 2016,-0.5
Sat Oct 01 00:43:18 +0000 2016,0
Sat Oct 01 00:43:41 +0000 2016,-1
Sat Oct 01 00:43:54 +0000 2016,-0.5
Sat Oct 01 00:43:56 +0000 2016,-0.5
```

`df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', names=['date', 'score'], index_col=['date'],parse_dates=['date'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rolling` for this use case, see the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html). Also check the [dedicated documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows) for more detail on resampling vs. rolling.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Some test data
zz = """date, value
"Sat Oct 01 00:43:02 +0000 2016",-0.5
"Sat Oct 01 05:43:18 +0000 2016",0
"Sat Oct 01 11:43:41 +0000 2016",-1
"Sat Oct 01 20:43:54 +0000 2016",-0.5
"Sat Oct 01 23:43:56 +0000 2016",-0.5
"""

# Preparing the data Frame
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delimiter=',')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Resampling with rolling window with a mean
df.rolling('6H').mean().plot()
```

[image]

Notes

- The list of offsets that can be used for the rolling window size is given in [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) page.
- I've used the last API, previously dedicated methods have to be used for each stat for example `rolling_mean` for mean.